# How to compute 2D displacement vector for binary image registration?

Tags: image-processing, image-registration, morphological-operations

My inputs are several binary images like:[image: first binary image to be register][image: second binary image to be register]

They have globally the same content but may be unregistered as they are produced from a hand camera. What I would like to compute is the 2D displacement vector from the first image to the second. I use OpenCV and my first attempt was to compute feature points (SURF algorithm) and the affine transform between both images. But of course, feature description are kinda poor on a binary image, therefore the matching is difficult and the matching map very inaccurate.

Does anyone has an idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am somewhat surprised that feature points don't work that well. I have had success registering shapes like yours using either

- Harris points, this is a corner detector, in combination with the RANSAC algorithm. See the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris_affine_region_detector) or [Peter Kovesi](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/) his site
- Using a feature detector like SURF or SIFT in combination with an edge map of the image prior to feature detection followed by some form of robust matching.

**EDIT**

I gave it a go with matlab and tried some variations on this theme. Currently I use

- SIFT features from the edge map to ascertain rotation and scaling, although they are very small between the images you provided
- RANSAC for robust matching
- Cross correlation to ascertain the translation between the two images

[image: Robust match]
[image: Before registration]
[image: After registration]

Source on [github](https://github.com/mdiephuis/sandbox/tree/master/so).

An alternative for RANSAC could be the Hough transform voting/binning approach that was proposed by the inventor of SIFT, David Lowe.

Comment: I know Harris, but I don't have fast and robust matching algorithm to be sure I get the same points from one image to another. Plus, Ransac is not usable as is in OpenCV...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. It shows a nice way to perform this. I finally modified the way I do what I need to do, because features computation and matching is too CPU-intensive for me. Thanks anyway, you did a good job!

Comment: Stephane, could you please add your solution as well to the site?

Comment: well, the thing is I don't answer to the question asked so it's not relevant to put that here. What I did is a detection of the blobs of the image and a description of each blob by the minimum amount of points possible. I wanted the 2D displacement to compute a temporal accumulation, but I won't do that anymore, as a vectorial description of the blobs is sufficient.